# Multiple SQS Listeners from different AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-jms, region

We are currently consuming a single SQS queue to process messages.
However as extension of functionality, we need to support multiple regions with same queue name.

Current implementation of jmsListener is tied to a given SQS queue in a given region as below:

**SQSListener.java**

```
@Component
public class SQSListener {

    @Override
    @JmsListener(destination = "${QueueName}", concurrency = "${JmsThreadCount}")
    public void onMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {

    }
```

**SQSConfiguration.java**

```
@Component
@EnableJms
public class SQSConfig {
    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
         DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = null;
         try {
             factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
             factory.setConnectionFactory(getSqsConnectionFactory()); //passes credentials in local method call
             factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
             factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
         return factory;
    }



}
```

**Application.properties**

```
QueueName=xyz
JmsThreadCount=1-5
Regions=us-east-1, us-west-2 #*(newly added region)*
```

How can I make it generic to create multiple listener class implementations by regions specified in the configurations ?

Comment: There is no direct way to configure multiple region SQS listeners using Spring annotations, so figuring out if I can create multiple region specific JmsContainerFactory beans programmatically, and configure respective JmsListener classes programmatic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there is no direct way using spring framework's annotations to create listeners to listen to multiple queue's in multiple AWS regions (same queue name in multiple AWS regions), I was able to solve above problem by programmatic configuration of JMS Container Factory beans for each region, JMS Templates for each region, and JMS Listeners for each region.

I will post sample code in next few days, that may be useful to the community.

Comment: Hey @Amit Kaneria, can you post the sample code, I want to do something similar for my use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to SQS from different region . If you provide not the queue name but full https url of the SQS . I have applied this in my application and it worked

eg SQS http URL - https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/YOURACCOUNTNUMBER/YOURQUEUENAME

```
@SqsListener(value = "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/123456789/MYQUEUENAME
", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
protected void queueListener(String dataFomSQS, @Header("Acknowledgment") Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {}
```

Comment: My question is if you can configure to consume same queue name in multiple regions configured as : "regions : us-east-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1", and tomorrow these supported region list may be expanding.

Comment: No by default that is not supported . You can change that based on region if region is us-west-2 url would be https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/123456789/MYQUEUENAME if region is us-east-1 url would be https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789/MYQUEUENAME
"